# Simulate keypress on TextArea w/ Vanilla Javascript (with demo)

Tags: javascript

Using Vanilla JS (not jQuery), I want to dispatch a keyboard event with some info about the key that should be pressed, and I want the result to appear in the text area.

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

var keyEvent = new Event('keypress', {
  key: 'a',
  location: 0,
  which: 65,
  code: 'KeyA'
});

textarea.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6vc5e0tm/)

Comment: you are dispatching an event to the "air", you need to focus it on the textarea, but still I don't think it's possible:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219800/chrome-simulate-keypress-events-on-input-text-field-using-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome: Simulate keypress events on input text field using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219800/chrome-simulate-keypress-events-on-input-text-field-using-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dispatching a KeyboardEvent fails to produce the character in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910309/dispatching-a-keyboardevent-fails-to-produce-the-character-in-a-textarea)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll review them.

Comment: It is not supposed to work, even after you fix `Event` to [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dispatching keyboard event doesn't work in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163708/dispatching-keyboard-event-doesnt-work-in-javascript)